# How to add row of a dataframe in r if I have created named list having same name as columns of dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <-data.frame(x=1:2,y=5:6)
row <- list(x=10,y=20)
add_row(df,row)
```

Error: New rows can't add columns.
x Can't find column `row` in `.data`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

but

```
add_row(df,x=10,y=20)
   x  y
1  1  5
2  2  6
3 10 20
```

works. Please help me add named list into df?

Comment: try: `rbind(df, row)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rbind` as suggested by @DanY is an easy solution, to use `add_row` you can change row to `tibble` or `data.frame` :

```
library(tibble)

df <-data.frame(x=1:2,y=5:6)
row <- tibble(x=10,y=20)
add_row(df, row)

#   x  y
#1  1  5
#2  2  6
#3 10 20
```

Comment: Is this only working with a recent update to *tibble*? Seems to be failing for me over here.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me on tibble `3.0.1`. What's yours ?

Comment: 2.1.1 - might be time to update this particular system.